# EASY C++ (function call)

Tags: c, function, call

this program gives me the wrong answer like -88567.0000000000000  i dont know whats wrong

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

main()
{
    float voltage,current,result;

    puts("hello please enter the voltage  ");
    scanf("%f",&voltage);

    puts("\nhello please enter the current  ");
    scanf("%f",&current);

    result=calling(voltage,current);
    // result from function calling 
    printf("the answer is %f",result);      // display the result 
    getch();
}

    float  calling (float y,float x)
    {
        float ans;
        ans=y+x;
        return(ans);
    }
```

Comment: How should we know?  You don't show us the inputs you used.

Comment: How do you make it compile?

Comment: any input will result in the same number like -8633424.00000000

Comment: possible duplicate of [C imlicit declaration of a function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5272514/c-imlicit-declaration-of-a-function)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your program shouldn't compile and/or your compiler should give you a lot of diagnostics with such code. Please consider looking into some book or online resources, first, before you bother others asking questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put prototype

```
float  calling (float y,float x);
```

before main